# Can I use wxwidgets within my Win32 API programm

Tags: windows, svg, winapi, wxwidgets

I wanna use wxSVG to render SVG file in my Win32 program. But wxSVG is only used with wxWidgets toolkits. So I wanna know if it's possible to use wxWidgets in my origin Win32 program without change the Win32 framework?

Comment: it should be possible. But why not use nanosvg directly?

Comment: thanks for your answering. We have abandoned this plan.

Comment: what you will be using? It might help future readers...